# Is it possible to identify what KBs are included in a Windows rollup patch (or is that not the right way to look at this)?

Tags: windows

I have some software that is known to conflict with a specific patch (KBxxxxx), so until the vendor comes out with an update that fixes this conflict, I have to avoid installing that patch.

I'm assuming that Windows rollup patches include a stack of the various KB patches, but I haven't been able to identify a way to see what KBs are included.

I really don't want to not install patches, although that's an option (this is Windows server 2019).

I've done a fair bit of Googl'ing and I don't see an answer to these questions:

1. Can I identify the contents of a rollup patch?
2. Can I see if a particular KB was installed if it was part of a Rollup?
   . . So far, I've only been able to see what rollups were installed.
3. Can I remove a specific KB after the rollup has been installed?
4. Am I, in ignorance, approaching this the wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: It's fairly simple really. Any KB updated newer than the KB that you haven't referenced will fail. All fixes are included in all subsequent monthly updates. You are referencing a way of patching that has not existed for over 15 years.

Comment: The problem is that I need a way to decide which patch/rollup to NOT install.  I guess I'm looking at a situation where I just have to not install patches until the vendor catches up.

Comment: You can't install any patches.